# PS4 - Owning Disc & Digital

Tags: marvels-spider-man

So, a while back I purchased the new Spider-Man digitally because I thought it would be easier (rather than getting up, putting whatever disc is in the console back in its case, and then putting Spider-Man in, etc.) but I honestly wanted to get it on disc as well to show off that I indeed had the game but a question is going through my mind that I can't quite find online and that is "If I own a game digitally, download and play it, will I be able to play and keep my save data and such if I purchased a physical copy? And if yes, will owning a physical copy require me to then remove and put in the disc as if I only have it on disc or will it also act as a digital copy?"

Comment: If your sole purpose of buying a physical copy is to just show that you have a physical copy, why do you need to even worry about it? Just keep the digital version downloaded and play with that. Not like you can return it anyways, unless you can return digital games on PS. (Guessing you cant).

Answer (score 3):

I was in a similar boat to yours but in my case it was the other way around. I purchased a physical copy of Destiny 2 (sadly) and then got the game off PS+ when it was free. When I tried to launch the game without the disc in, I got a error saying that I should either insert the disc or download the digital version of the game.

I downloaded the digital version and all saves, trophies etc. were there and there was absolutely no problem.

But in your case, I would just leave the disc in its case just to show it off and continue playing the digital version.